# Azure Hybrid Connection Error: Assembly Microsoft.Web.Administration Version 7.0.0.0 be installed in the Global Assembly Cache first

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am getting this error every time I try to install the on premises hybrid connection manager needed to run Hybrid Connections:

[image: Azure Hybrid Connections Error]

I'm running the Download and Install client from Windows Server 2012 R2 from IE 11 off the Azure website.  I figured maybe installing Visual Studio 2013 may also resolve this error but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the package in your local machine by using following command command prompt.
gacutil /i {Path(location where your package is present) assemblyname)